# looking for a tool that can scan for windows api compatibility issues

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, testing

I am looking for a tool that can scan for windows api compatibility, either it is based on code scan or binary scan. For example, INetFwPolicy2's Minimum supported client requires Windows Vista, so if it is used on XP, it will fail. I am wondering whether there is a tool or an easy way to dig out such OS incompatible issues?
Thanks.

Comment: The [Microsoft Application Compatability Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7352) is probably a good start.

Comment: How would the code (or binary for that matter) know what OS it was going to be run on? Or are you just after warnings of potential issues?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a "tool" for this; the SDK headers are already carefully protected with include guards that are sensitive to version compatibility.

All you need to do is define your target version of Windows *before* you include `windows.h`. Any symbols *not* supported by your target version will not even be defined in the headers, resulting in a compile-time error.

For example, in your pre-compiled header, you might have:

```
// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.
// 
// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform,
// include WinSDKVer.h and set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform
// you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT  _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP   // target Windows XP
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>

#include <Windows.h>
```

Visual Studio even does this for you automatically when you use one of the built-in templates to create a new project.

[The SDK documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) provides a complete listing of the values needed to target various Windows versions. But the most common ones you'll need are `_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP` for Windows XP, `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA` for Windows Vista/Server 2008, `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7` for Windows 7/Server 2008 R2, and `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8` for Windows 8.

Comment: Unfortunately every now and then some stuff slips through these guards so it's not foolproof.

Comment: @Luke Do you have any examples? I've never encountered something that has "slipped through". In fact, it's quite impossible for something to slip through existing guards, so the only way that could happen is if the guards were never added to the Windows headers in the first place. And I guess the dev team at Microsoft is human and could always make mistakes, but I'd expect this to be so rare as to be negligible.

Comment: I don't remember the specific instance I ran into, but I believe it was a function introduced in Windows Vista.  In trying to research it I came across [this post](http://www.kndr.org/windows-sdk-brokenness); no idea how accurate it is, though.

Comment: How does this work? _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP is defined within SDKDDKVer.h. You probably should be using the hex constants in SDKDDKVer.h. For example: #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501